# How to add timer into connect four? Java

Tags: java, arrays, timer, 2d-games

A bit of an unconventional question but I wanted to know if anyone had any ideas on a way to implement a timer into a connect four game (2 players). I currently have functioning code for the regular game, but want to add a way where the user has 5 seconds to make a move or the computer will make a random move for them. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be accomplished? Here is my main function to handle decision making every turn.

```
public void handleAction (int x, int y)
    {
    if (gameOver)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Please Select Game...New to start a new game",
            "Game Over", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    int column = (x - BORDER_SIZE) / SQUARE_SIZE + 1;
    int row = findNextRow (board, column);

    if (row <= 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Please Select another Column",
            "Column is Full", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    animatePiece (currentPlayer, column, row);
    board [row] [column] = currentPlayer;

    int winner = checkForWinner (board, row, column);


    if (winner == BANANA)
    {
        gameOver = true;
        repaint ();
        backgroundMusic.stop();
        winBanana.play();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Banana Wins!!!",
            "GAME OVER", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
    else if (winner == STRAWBERRY)
    {
        gameOver = true;
        repaint ();
        backgroundMusic.stop();
        winStrawberry.play();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Strawberry Wins!!!",
            "GAME OVER", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        currentPlayer *= -1;
        if (currentPlayer == 1)
            addStrawberry.play();
        else
            addBanana.play();

    }   
    currentColumn = 3;

    repaint ();
}
```

Comment: ALWAYS include code. Some ways of implementing a timer can be better or worse depending on how your program is organized.

Comment: @MarsAtomic just did

Answer (score 0):

The **java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()** method would help you achieve this.

To begin implementing this into your program, you would need to record the current time at every point a new move is made.

Then you would have to implement a reoccurring loop to record the time each second from the moment it switches to the other player, I would recommend a while loop with a 1 second delay before recording the current time.

Then you would need an if statement for when the timer reaches however long you want before the system makes the random move. Here's some basic code to start you off:

```
long start, end, timeElapsed;

start = System.currentTimeMillis();

while(.....){
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    timeElapsed = (endstart)/1000;
}

if(timeElapsed == ....){
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: This is an incomplete solution. If time elapses, fine, but what if the user makes his move before your timer runs out? How do you handle that? As it stands, your timer will *always* run out and make a move on behalf of the user.